# Is the union of two analytic curves at their point of tangency to each other analytic?

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Suppose I have two circles, of radii $1$ and $R <<1$, respectively. Denote the boundary of the first circle of radius $1$ by $\gamma_{1}$. Denote the boundary of circle of radius $R$ by $\gamma_{2}$. I position $\gamma_{2}$ in the interior of $\gamma_{1}$, such that $\gamma_{2}$ is $\mathbf{tangent}$ to $\gamma_{1}$ at one point.

Now each circle individually is clearly an analytic curve (or generally, an analytic manifold). What about the curve $\gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2}$? Is it also analytic everywhere, or is it no longer differentiable at the point of tangency?

I am guessing it is indeed still analytic, if one uses the formal definition of a manifold with its fundamental characteristics ($\gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2}$ can be covered by a countable collection of open sets, such that there exists a $C^{\omega}$ diffeomorphism on each open set taking it to $\mathbb{R}$).

To make things very precise. Parametrise $\gamma_{1}$  by $\varphi$ as

$$\gamma_{1}(\varphi) = \{(\cos \varphi, \sin \varphi): \quad \varphi \in (-\pi, \pi) \}.$$

Parametrise $\gamma_{2}$ by $\phi$ as

$$\gamma_{1}(\varphi) = \{(-R\cos \phi - (1-R), R\sin \phi): \quad \phi \in (0, 2\pi) \}.$$

Geometrically on the $(x,y)$ plane this means that $\gamma_{1}$ centre is at the origin, while $\gamma_{2}$ centre is at $(-1+R, 0)$; $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2}$ are tangent to each other at $(-1,0)$.

Is the resulting union of two circles analytic (at $(-1,0)$) ?

Comment: Can we union the analytic \ and / to get V (which has a singular point)?

Comment: In your example, clearly it is not true, as the derivatives at a singular point of \ and / are different and they are not tangent. But what about my example, where $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2}$ have a point of (infinite) order tangency? @CalvinKhor

Comment: Of course, its more a comment on your title rather than the body

Comment: Yes, sorry - title edited @CalvinKhor

Answer (score 0):

At the point $x \in \gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2$ where the circles $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ are tangent, the following fact is true: for every sufficiently small open neighborhood $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ of $x$, the set 
$$\bigl(U \cap (\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2)\bigr) - \{x\}
$$ 
has at least four connected components: two open arcs on $\gamma_1$ incident to $x$, and two open arcs on $\gamma_2$ incident to $x$.

It follows that $\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2$ is not even a *topological* $1$-manifold at the point $x$, let alone an analytic $1$-manifold: if it were a topological 1-manifold, then there would exist arbitrarily small open neighborhoods $U \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ of $x$ such that $U-x$ has exactly two connected components.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify: $\gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2}$ is not analytic as a curve too (let alone a 1-manifold), right? More generally, is every $C^{r}$ curve a  $C^{r} $  one-dimensional manifold? @Lee Mosher

Comment: P.S. Also: if $\gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2}$ is not analytic, is there an explanation why, in terms of the tangent vectors' directions at the point $x \in \gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2}$? Heuristically, if $\gamma_{1}$ and $\gamma_{2}$ had a transverse intersection at $x$, then I see why their union is not analytic: the two tangents have different directions. But here they coincide at all orders, right?... Is "infinite order tangency" a correct term to describe this situation? @Lee Mosher

Comment: To ask whether "$\gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2$ is analytic as a curve" does not quite make sense without a more careful formulation. Perhaps you could concatenate or compose the parameterized curves $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(topology)#Path_composition, and ask whether the resulting parameterized curve is analytic. For that to be the case, at the very minimum the one-sided derivatives of all orders must match up at the concatenation point, which is not gonna happen for parameterized circular arcs of different radius.